# How to debug java microservices on openshift cluster

Tags: java, debugging, openshift, microservices

My java microservice mesh is deployed on openshift cluster and I am looking for a way to debug a particular (the buggy one) microservice locally.
I have tried the squash debugger and telepresence but nothing worked for me as squash provides support for java on intelliJ and I am using eclipse (Can't pay for intelliJ) and telepresence is not able to find my pod which is already existing on my openshift cluster.

Comment: what mesh is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

1. For the buggy microservice, in your POD configuration file open up the java JPDA port. So instead of

`java -jar yourapp.jar`

give this:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=<port> -jar <yourapp>.jar
```

2. Expose the jpda port as mentioned in `<port>` parameter in above command via your POD configuration YAML file. This will ensure that your pod is accessible to external network during boot.
3. Connect via eclipse remote debugger.

Comment: By POD configuration file you mean the YAML file ? If so , then I do not have "java -jar yourapp.jar" in YAML file and if not where should I give this command.

Comment: can you attach your YAML file here

Comment: This I cannot do but if you can tell me the property name then I can configure it.

Comment: look at the `containers.args` property for the container that you are facing issue with

Answer (score 0):

The [Squash debugger](https://github.com/solo-io/squash) is compatible with the [Community Edition of Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download) (free) - perhaps this will meet your needs until the Eclipse plugin is available.